# How do I get GIT on PATH in Heroku Review App using Docker?

Tags: git, docker, heroku, dockerfile

Recently my Heroku Review Apps using Docker stoped building.  They were previously behaving as expected, but it now appears that npm cannot find git on the PATH.

My first guess was that for some reason I now need install git into the carbon-alpine.  See my attempt below with where I added 'RUN npm install --no-cache git'

Any help would be appreciated!  I also really like to know why it was behaving as expected.

### Dockerfile-heroku

```
FROM node:carbon-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . .

# Build Angular
RUN npm install --no-cache git
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

WORKDIR ./server

# Build Webserver
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "./bin/www"]
```

### Error Message

```
Step 4/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in f8800495a4ab
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-28T13_15_27_080Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: I think I found a solution here: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/586.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom [nodejs/docker-node](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node) image is:

- [based on alpine](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/dd6d7a3ba9fea4ec65216a473d88037249600bd1/11/alpine/Dockerfile#L1)
- do add Git, as [shown in PR 367](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/pull/367/files) (this is not yet integrated in the official image, so you will have to define your own for now)

Comment: Thanks VonC, this was very similar to the solution I ended up using.  I still don't understand why it was working and now it's not, but sometimes life is a mystery.